# How come my combo box in access is either showing duplicates or no values at all?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Terms:

`[main checks].ID` is the auto number generated for every row added

`[main checks].Account` is the field I want the combo box to take unique values on

When I use the combo box wizard, this is what it generates:

```
SELECT [main checks].ID, [main checks].Account
FROM [main checks];
```

[image: Combo Box Wizard]

So I tried using what I found on previous questions here as well as from google where I should add `SELECT DISTINCT` to the SQL query as one option. The other option is to go to the "Row Source" then in the query builder, I make "Unique Values" from "No" to "Yes". I believe this does the same thing because the SQL query automatically adds the `SELECT DISTINCT` portion.

The revised code is shown below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [main checks].ID, [main checks].Account
FROM [main checks];
```

[image: Same issue]
As can be seen the combo box still shows duplicates and does not resolve the issue.

My third attempt is to remove the `[main checks].ID` portion of the SQL statement and just leave the `[main checks].Account` portion. This makes me combo box blank I don't know why. The code is shown below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [main checks].Account
FROM [main checks];
```

[image: Blank combo box]

Screenshot of my Table with values:
[image: Table]

Below is my property sheet of the combo box for the events:

[image]

Data Tab of property sheet:

[image]

Format Tab:

[image]

Comment: Can you suggest what query I should make for the combo box? I'm out of ideas

Comment: show both columns and its data,otherwise its not clear

Comment: Alright hold on

Comment: Could you provide your binding combo box  code ?

Comment: Binding combo box code? Sorry I don't know what that is isn't that the SQL codes I posted in the main post?

Comment: How do you show combo box?

Comment: I added a photo. I am not sure if the "On Click" is what you meant?

Comment: The `Row Source` SQL commands are the codes shown in the main post above. Those 3 are the ones I tried there. None of them worked. That's what I need help on I believe

Comment: Is there any data exist when you execute sql `SELECT DISTINCT [main checks].Account FROM [main checks];` on the ssms?

Comment: Nothing that was my 3rd attempt it returns a blank combo box

Comment: Why would you even include the checks table record ID? You don't have a lookup table for the account types? Users are allowed to enter any value into the field? Edit question to show the combobox properties: ColumnCount, BoundColumn, ControlSource, ColumnWidths as well as RowSource.

Comment: I just used the combo box wizard I have no idea if I did it correctly. I just saw the accounts appear, but there are duplicates. So I checked online how to address the duplicates. But then they are not working. I added the format tab that contains ColumnCount and Column Widths. The BoundColumn and RowSource are already there

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming issue. It is form design.

Comment: If you pull only the one field into the RowSource then change ColumnCount to 1 and ColumnWidths to nothing. Really should use a lookup table. You are pulling values from the data table which means for a brand new empty db there will be no items to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the existing values as Dropdown content is a valid approach to e.g. avoid spelling mistakes for free-text fields.

But you can't use the ID in that SQL, that makes each row unique.
Use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [main checks].Account
FROM [main checks];
```

and change the combo box properties to `Column count = 1`, and adapt the `Column widths` to a single value (or empty).

Comment: In the main post I included that SQL statement. I changed my `column count` from 2 to 1 as mentioned, and `column widths` by default is `0";1"` But it still returns blanks

Comment: That's *two* values in Column widths. But you only have one column, and it gets the first width = zero. Change that to `1"` or empty. @MarcSantos

Answer (score 0):

in rowsource write the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT MASTERFILE.FIELD FROM MASTERFILE

CHANGE COLUMN COUNT TO 1
CHANGE COLUMN WIDTH TO (none)
```

change rowsourcetype to 3-SQL STATEMENT